# Rails - Import JSON to database

Tags: json, import, ruby-on-rails-5

I am still learning with Rails so enlighten me please.

**I have a json data and I want this to be imported on my database.**

For my model relations:

```
class Account
 has_many :documents
 has_many :costs
 has_many :suppliers
 has_one :logo
end

class Document
 has_many :document_details
 has_many :payments
 belongs_to :account
end

class DocumentDetail
 belongs_to :document
end

class Cost,Supplier,Logo
 belongs_to :account
end
```

Here is my sample.json

```
{
account: {
  id: 1,
  company: "account1",
  created_at: "2017-01-11T12:48:00.107Z",
  updated_at: "2017-08-10T11:10:56.318Z",
  documents: [{
    id: 1,
    user_id: null,
    account_id: 1,
      document_details: [
        {
          id: 1,
          document_id: 1,
          title: "test11",
          description: "test1x"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          document_id: 1,
          title: "test12",
          description: ""
        }
      ],
      payments: [ ]
    }],
  costs: [
  {
    id: 1,
    account_id: 1,
    amount: 2,
    supplier_id: 1,
    invoice: "12",
    tax: 1,
    created_at: "2017-08-10T11:11:14.582Z",
    updated_at: "2017-08-10T11:11:14.582Z"
  }
  ],
  suppliers: [
  {
    id: 1,
    account_id: 1,
    title: "Mme",
    created_at: "2017-08-10T11:03:55.334Z",
    updated_at: "2017-08-10T11:03:55.334Z"
  }
  ],
  setting: {
    id: 1,
    account_id: 1,
    created_at: "2017-08-10T12:31:22.400Z",
    updated_at: "2017-08-10T12:31:22.400Z"
  },
  logo: {
    id: 1,
    account_id: 1,
    logo_base64: "logobase64"
  }
}
}
```

> Any thoughts on how I can do this or any gem I can use ?